Load React or Angular Component In OpenFin
I am trying to get an OpenFin app to run using the Platform API: https://developers.openfin.co/of-docs/docs/platform-getting-started
I can get a 'platform' running, and x2 panels using the example in the above. However these panels are loading URLs from an external source ie:
"url": "https://cdn.openfin.co/embed-web/chart.html"

My 'platform' consists of a number of small React components - grids, tables, forms etc
How can i pass in a component for each panel rather than a URL?
I have considered a uniform URL that accepts a component name in the URL then loads and returns that component, but from a performance perspective alone, that sounds awful esp with each component have to make dupe'd backend calls for things like user auth, app config etc which is currently a 1-time call on app load then cached.
What id like to do is:
    {
  "snapshot": {
    "windows": [
      {
        "defaultWidth": 600,
        "defaultHeight": 600,
        "layout": {
          "content": [
            {
              "type": "stack",
              "content": [
                {
                  "type": "component",
                  "componentName": "view",
                  "componentState": {
                    "name": "component_A1",
                    "processAffinity": "ps_1",
                    // "url": "https://www.example.com" <-- load component here ie import MyGrid from '../widgets/grid/userGrid.tsx';
                  }
                },


I don't think you can. Web apps are served on a url; OpenFin is a layout manager. Well, plus a lot of other things, but for the purpose of showing multiple web apps as one, it is just a layout manager.
